# sails-mysql username cannot accept special characters

Tags: sails.js

I am deploying the sailsjs code to a production environment where the username has a special character. For example, user@sitename

As of Sails v1 onwards, the mysql connection is based on a URL string format.

```
mysql://user@site1:myPassWord@localhost:3306/awesomedbname
```

If we have "@" for the username, the site1 becomes the host.

Anyone knows how to fix this?